# How to break out goquery Each loop in Go

Tags: go, goquery

Could you help me break out a loop of goquery Each looping?
I used "return" but it doesn't get out of loop, just pass the iteraction...
How can I break out an Each looping in the following code:

```
doc.Find("td").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    summary := s.Text()
    if summary == "--" {
        //I want to break the Each loop here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`EachWithBreak`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.EachWithBreak) method

```
doc.Find("td").EachWithBreak(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) bool {
    summary := s.Text()
    if summary == "--" {
        return false
    }
    return true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In goquery 1.7.1 [iteration.go](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/blob/6a7f1c4a50e1f8b451b8703e06b28f171abc3d28/iteration.go#L19), it says:

> It is identical to Each except that it is possible to break out of the  loop by returning false in the callback function.

So you need to return **false** to break the loop.

Comment: Always add a link to the documentation you refer to as well as paste the relevant part into the response (as you did), and add a snippet of code if applicable, so that you can give more complete information next time. It also points out that `EachWithBreak` should be used instead of `Each`.